# How to access UMD module provided in minified js in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, umd

I have to include a third party widget into my React+TS app.

The widget is shipped in a minified js file and according to their documentation it can be included in a script tag or through e.g. requireJS.

What I cannot wrap my head around is that - as far as I understand - both methods above include the widget at runtime as window.Widget. However, I would like to interact with the widget from my TypeScript code as it exposed different methods.
Is that at all possible? Obviously, I could include my own logic outside TS/React, but I'd prefer to keep it inside.
If that's not possible, is there another way I could communicate with the widget other than maybe through my server?

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm a bit stuck right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I feel pretty stupid. It turns out, I can download the minified js file and just import it into my project. It doesn't have any types, but it works.

```
import * as Widget from "../lib/widget.min";
```